# How do I implement SSO that can connect to multiple Active directories?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I need to implement user authentication by reading from multiple Active Directories. If this is possible, what would be the standard way of storing configuration details of each directory(ClientId, ClientSecret, AADInstance, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach here is generally to build a multi-tenant application. A multi-tenant application allows users from *any* Azure AD organization to sign in, and then simply checks if the signed-in user is from one of the expected tenants.

With this approach, your app only has one single client ID and one single credential (I highly recommend using key credentials, rather than password credentials (i.e. client secret)), which is used when any user from any organization is signing in.

"Provisioning" of your app into each tenant is done when the user first signs in and consent to your app.

More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps

An in-depth end-to-end guide for building a multi-tenant app: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the users from multiple domains to a security group?
Then you just need to authorize the security group.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="SecurityGroup" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
```